# Sync Database with XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api

I am thinking about a system which includes XML or XML-like tech. My scenario, i have products in my database tables and i want to export these products, so any user can get my product list with an XML or another way and import their system. It is common usage, i know but i wonder, how can i sync the product quantities. What will be happen, if any user sell my product. How can i edit the quantity field in my DB  ? Which technologies can i use ? I think API will be best but how can i use XML  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a public api.
users should create an account and you give them an api-key in order to access the api.
you give them a `GET` method with they use to recieve the product list and a `POST` method to report the purchases. Once the purchase comes in from the user, you update the records accordingly in your database.

MVC 4 has some good capabilities to create api.

See below:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

[How to return Xml Data from a Web API Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366096/how-to-return-xml-data-from-a-web-api-method)

[Creating REST API for existing MVC based website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583975/creating-rest-api-for-existing-mvc-based-website)

Comment: what if i can only need to give an xml file to end user, and ens user make a sell.. How can i reduce the quantity ?

Comment: u have to have a mechanism listening for user to report sell. no other way around it.

Comment: I think this mechanism has no relation with the XML right ? Consider, i gave an XML to the customer. And a product has 10 quantity, and one of them sold. So how can i edit the XML which customer has ? I think customer's program should do this. And i need to recognize and reduce the count in supplier, right ?

Comment: once your api recieves a call and updates the database, from that point on, the GET request's output will be the updated xml.

Comment: i am wonderin how can get a receive to my api from only an xml file ? woth the link in the XML ?

Comment: no, your post request has a body. you can put your xml or json in the body of your post request which converts to a model on your api server.